# Limit of a quotient with a radical in the numerator

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

I have a limit but I'm so confused in how to rationalize the numerator because it has two numbers separated. How should I change the signs, please help me out.

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 6}{\sqrt{x+10}-x+2\over 3x-18}$$

Comment: The numerator is still on the form $\sqrt{a}-b$, so you just mulltiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{a}+b$. Here, $a=x+10$ and $b=x-2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerator is $\sqrt{x+10} - (x-2)$, so let's multiply the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x+10} + (x-2)$. This gives us:

$\dfrac{\sqrt{x+10} - (x-2)}{3x-18}$

$= \dfrac{\sqrt{x+10} - (x-2)}{3x-18} \cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{x+10} + (x-2)}{\sqrt{x+10} + (x-2)}$

$= \dfrac{(x+10)-(x-2)^2}{(3x-18)(\sqrt{x+10} + (x-2))}$

$= \dfrac{-x^2+5x+6}{(3x-18)(\sqrt{x+10} + (x-2))}$

$= \dfrac{-(x+1)(x-6)}{3(x-6)(\sqrt{x+10} + (x-2))}$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Yes!!, thank you, I already finished it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** you can write $-x+2$ as $-(x-2)$

**Another hint:** Multiply by the conjugate: $$\frac{\sqrt{x+10}+(x-2)}{\sqrt{x+10}+(x-2)}$$ And recall that $(\alpha - \beta)(\alpha + \beta) = \alpha^2 - \beta^2$.

Comment: I have a question, Doesn't it matters that the $-x+2$ are without the brackets?, Can I put the brackets without any problem?

Comment: $-x+2 = -x -(-2) = -1(x+(-2)) = -(x-2)$, you're really forcing a common factor. I did that in order to be able to tell what's $\alpha$ and what's $\beta$.